# Implementation of captcha in magento?

Tags: magento, captcha, contacts

How to implement a captcha in a Magento site? I want to implement a captcha (like 2+3=? ) in contact us form.

thanks.

Comment: I tried before Recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Which version of magento you are using.In Magento Community edition 1.7.0.2.There is option for captcha in the Admin section.

Do some search on Google you will find the answer.

Comment: i searched but i didnt get the result ..i installed recaptcha and its working correctly..actually i want math captcha(like 3+4=?)